# Village not found when typing its name in search bar

Tags: overpass-turbo, guinea

When I visit the site https://overpass-turbo.eu/, I write the name of my village, `Tomba Kanssa`, in the search bar on on the top right corner.

But the result doesn't show it rendered unless I snapshot the map down to the village level.

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?

The place is already on OSM : https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/10961683446

Comment: Link to the place https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/10961683446

Answer (score 1):

What search bar are you referring to?

The one on https://www.openstreetmap.org/? If so, then I don't see a problem. It should work:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Tomba%20Kanssa#map=11/11.6462/-10.0346

The results are not highlighted on the map, but they are shown in the results panel. See image below of my results. Note that I'm hovering on one of the results, hence it is shown on the map.

[image: image showing result of a search results]

Your question is also tagged with the `overpass-api` tag. Which could refer to https://overpass-turbo.eu/.

If that is the case, you should share the query you are using so that we can have a look and debug. Below is an example query, assuming you are interested in the location as a point.

```
[out:json];
// Search for nodes with the name "Tomba Kanssa"
node["place"="town"]["name"="Tomba Kanssa"];
out;
```

Just make sure to manually move/zoom the map to the location. The map will not to that automatically, possibly creating the impression that no results have been found.

If I have misunderstood your question, and your data is indeed not in OpenStreetMap. Then a solution would be to add it yourself! That's the whole idea behind OSM, everyone can contribute.

Comment: Hello my problem is that when I open the overpass turbo page, then typed his name in the search bar displayed at the top right of the map, The results that appear I do not see fell kanssa, on this list Here is the result of this query https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1xeO

Comment: @BereteBaba Better to update your question to make your question clearer, I just did a little. You can notice that people doesn't understand your question and they didn't answer what you wanted ;-)

Comment: I took a screenshot but I can't post it on the forum I say my problem is not on openstreetmap, but rather overpass turbo I say when I open the overpass turbo page then type in the search bar the name of my village the result that appears we do not see the name of my village tomba kanssa,

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question. I don't have a fix, but here is some context for others.

The search field you are referring to is requesting data from the https://osmnames.org api, and not directly from OpenStreetMap. OpenStreetMap data is processed before made available to the osmnames API. I see 3 possible issues:

1) 'Tomba Kanssa' couldn't be processed and has been left out
2) The ranking/ordering of the search result leaves the location out. Try variations of the name by including names of administrative regions
3) The osmnames API data is not up to date